# Insert Unicode text file data into database

Tags: node.js, csv

I need a solution for getting data out of a text file that is unicode encoded and write this data into an existing database. I am working with node.js

My text file looks like this (whitespaces are shown)
[Text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wd7y3.png)

```
Column  Active  Description Number
1   True    test test   0000
1   True    test1 test1 0001
1   True    test2 test2 0002
1   True    test3 test3 0003
1   True    test4 test4 0004
```

I need to get the values of column, active, description and number for each row in order to create a new entry in my database with the respective values. My database already exists and has the columns Column, Active, Description and Number. What is the eaisest way to write the data of the text file into my database. I tried a csv parser

```
const csv = require('csv-streamify');
const fs = require('fs');

const parser = csv({
  delimiter: '\t',
  columns: true,
});

parser.on('data', (line) => {
  console.log(line)
})

fs.createReadStream('test.txt').pipe(parser)
```

but that only showed me output like this:

```
{ '��C\u0000o\u0000l\u0000u\u0000m\u0000n ...
```

How do i get the correct output and what do i have to do to write the data into the database?

I think it has to be something like this:

```
connection.query('INSERT INTO Table1 SET ...
```

I really don't know how to continue.

Comment: The link that says "Text file" is actually to a PNG image file.  Can you correct that?  If it's a short file including it directly as text in the question is best.

Comment: Of course, here you are

Answer (score 0):

Using 'byline' instead of 'csv-streamify', you can retrieve the content as follows:

```
const byline = require('byline');
const fs = require('fs');

var stream = byline(fs.createReadStream('test.txt'));
var index = 0;
var headers;
var data = [];

stream.on('data', function(line) {
    var currentData;
    var entry;
    var i;

    line = line.toString(); // Convert the buffer stream to a string line
    if (index === 0) {
        headers = line.split(/[ ]+/);
    } else {
        currentData = line.split(/[ ]+/);
        entry = {};
        for (i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
            entry[headers[i]] = currentData[i];
        }
        data.push(entry);
    }
    index++;
});
stream.on("error", function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
stream.on("end", function() {
    console.log(data);
    console.log("Done");
});
```

Everything is stored in the 'data' array as follows:

```
    [ { Column: '1',
    Active: 'True',
    Description: 'test',
    Number: 'test' },
  { Column: '1',
    Active: 'True',
    Description: 'test1',
    Number: 'test1' },
  { Column: '1',
    Active: 'True',
    Description: 'test2',
    Number: 'test2' },
  { Column: '1',
    Active: 'True',
    Description: 'test3',
    Number: 'test3' },
  { Column: '1',
    Active: 'True',
    Description: 'test4',
    Number: 'test4' } ]
```

Then, it shouldn't be too difficult to write to the SQL database.

Comment: Thank you but i still got the problem, that the output looks like this: `{
    '��D\u0000u\u0000m\u0000m\u0000y\u0000C\u0000o\...`. I would have to change the encoding from unicode to ANSI manually.

Comment: No need to do that manually. You can adapt the code above using `Buffer.from(yourUnicodeString, 'utf-8')` in order to convert the Unicode into a readable UTF8 format.

Comment: So where do i have to change it?

Comment: After `line = line.toString();` you can add `line = Buffer.from(line, 'utf-8');`.

Comment: Now there occurs the following error: `line.split is not a fuction`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, you should apply `line = Buffer.from(line, 'utf-8').toString();` instead.

Comment: Now it works again but nothing has changed in the output `'��C\u0000o\u0000l\u0000u\u0000m\u0000n\u0000\t\u0000A\u0000c\u0000t\u0000i\u0000v\u0000e\u0000\t\...`. Is that Unicode at all? I don't understand why it does not get converted.

Comment: Strange... Could you upload the text file, so that I can check this on my side?